# How do I submit a report form so it goes to a specific email in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, email, submit

I am trying to set up a report post screen for a social media app with React Native where users can report an inappropriate or spam post.  I just want the user to select a reason and then it sends directly to a specific email.  This is what I have on my frontend so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function ReportScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Why are you reporting this?</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.panelButton}
                onPress={() => {
                    this.handleSubmit();
                }}
            >
                <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>It's abusive or harmful</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.panelButton}
                onPress={() => {
                    this.handleSubmit();
                }}
            >
                <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>
                    It's inappropriate or offensive
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.panelButton}
                onPress={() => {
                    this.handleSubmit();
                }}
            >
                <Text style={styles.panelButtonTitle}>Cancel</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go Back" />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: You need a backend to perform the task of sending an email. You cannot send on react-native frontend itself. The only thing you can do is use mailto:example@example to redirect the user to his/her email client.